# fail2ban not working on fresh install of ubuntu 14.04, why?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, iptables, fail2ban

After installing and configuring fail2ban, I tried to login to my server through ssh with a wrong password. After a few attempts, I tried with the correct password with success. So, fail2ban didn't banned the user ip allowing him to login. Regardless of the rules I've set, maxretry = 1, etc.

My iptables -L output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Here's the debug log, not complete version follows:

```
root@host:~# fail2ban-client -v -v -v start
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
INFO   Using socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.local', '/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables.conf
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-blocktype.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-blocktype.local', '/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables.conf']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

[...] SKIPPED SOME READING CONFIG FILES here

DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
DEBUG  Reading configs for /etc/fail2ban/jail under /etc/fail2ban 
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
DEBUG  Reading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
INFO   [#         ] Waiting on the server...DEBUG  Starting '/usr/bin/fail2ban-server' with args ['fail2ban-server', '-b', '-s', '/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock', '-p', '/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid']
2014-05-22 15:29:14,376 fail2ban.server : INFO   Starting Fail2ban v0.8.11
2014-05-22 15:29:14,376 fail2ban.server : INFO   Starting in daemon mode
DEBUG  OK : 'pong'

DEBUG  OK : 3
DEBUG  OK : '/var/log/fail2ban.log'
DEBUG  OK : 'ssh'
DEBUG  OK : 'warn'
DEBUG  OK : ['/var/log/auth.log']
DEBUG  OK : 1
DEBUG  OK : ['127.0.0.1/8']
DEBUG  OK : 600
DEBUG  OK : 600
DEBUG  OK : ['^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:error: PAM: )?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error) for .* from (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\\w\\-.^_]*\\w)( via \\S+)?\\s*$']
DEBUG  OK : ['^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:error: PAM: )?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error) for .* from (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\\w\\-.^_]*\\w)( via \\S+)?\\s*$', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\\w\\-.^_]*\\w)\\s*$']

[...] SKIPPED SOME REGEX HERE

DEBUG  OK : 'iptables'
DEBUG  OK : 'iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>'
DEBUG  OK : 'iptables -D <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>\niptables -F fail2ban-<name>\niptables -X fail2ban-<name>'
DEBUG  OK : 'iptables -N fail2ban-<name>\niptables -A fail2ban-<name> -j RETURN\niptables -I <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>'
DEBUG  OK : 'iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip> -j <blocktype>'
DEBUG  OK : "iptables -n -L <chain> | grep -q 'fail2ban-<name>[ \\t]'"
DEBUG  OK : 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable'
DEBUG  OK : 'tcp'
DEBUG  OK : 'SSH'
DEBUG  OK : 'INPUT'
DEBUG  OK : 'ssh'
DEBUG  OK : None
```

My fail2ban.log, jail.local:

```
tail /var/log/fail2ban.log
2014-05-22 15:30:27,729 fail2ban.server : INFO   Exiting Fail2ban
2014-05-22 15:30:32,668 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.11
2014-05-22 15:30:32,668 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh'
2014-05-22 15:30:32,668 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' uses poller
2014-05-22 15:30:32,679 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Initiated 'polling' backend
2014-05-22 15:30:32,680 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2014-05-22 15:30:32,681 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 1
2014-05-22 15:30:32,681 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2014-05-22 15:30:32,682 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
2014-05-22 15:30:32,716 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
```

tail /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[ssh]
enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
filter = sshd
maxretry = 1
action = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
port = ssh


tail /var/log/auth.log
```

tail /var/log/auth.log is empty!

root@host:~# fail2ban-client -d

```
['set', 'loglevel', 3]
['set', 'logtarget', '/var/log/fail2ban.log']
['add', 'ssh', 'polling']
['set', 'ssh', 'usedns', 'warn']
['set', 'ssh', 'addlogpath', '/var/log/auth.log']
['set', 'ssh', 'maxretry', 1]
['set', 'ssh', 'addignoreip', '127.0.0.1/8']
['set', 'ssh', 'findtime', 600]
['set', 'ssh', 'bantime', 600]
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:error: PAM: )?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error) for .* from <HOST>( via \\S+)?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*Failed \\S+ for .*? from <HOST>(?: port \\d*)?(?: ssh\\d*)?(: (ruser .*|(\\S+ ID \\S+ \\(serial \\d+\\) CA )?\\S+ (?:[\\da-f]{2}:){15}[\\da-f]{2}(, client user ".*", client host ".*")?))?\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*ROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*refused connect from \\S+ \\(<HOST>\\)\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', '^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups\\s*$']
['set', 'ssh', 'addfailregex', "^\\s*(<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>)?\\s*(?:\\S+ )?(?:kernel: \\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\] )?(?:@vserver_\\S+ )?(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)?\\s(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\])?\\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\\s*$"]
['set', 'ssh', 'addaction', 'iptables']
['set', 'ssh', 'actionban', 'iptables', 'iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>']
['set', 'ssh', 'actionstop', 'iptables', 'iptables -D <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>\niptables -F fail2ban-<name>\niptables -X fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'ssh', 'actionstart', 'iptables', 'iptables -N fail2ban-<name>\niptables -A fail2ban-<name> -j RETURN\niptables -I <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'ssh', 'actionunban', 'iptables', 'iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip> -j <blocktype>']
['set', 'ssh', 'actioncheck', 'iptables', "iptables -n -L <chain> | grep -q 'fail2ban-<name>[ \\t]'"]
['set', 'ssh', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'blocktype', 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable']
['set', 'ssh', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'protocol', 'tcp']
['set', 'ssh', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'name', 'SSH']
['set', 'ssh', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'chain', 'INPUT']
['set', 'ssh', 'setcinfo', 'iptables', 'port', 'ssh']
['start', 'ssh']
```

Other info:

```
dpkg -l |grep fail  
ii  fail2ban                         0.8.11-1                      all          ban hosts that cause multiple authentication errors


/etc/init.d/fail2ban status      
 * Status of authentication failure monitor                                                                             *  fail2ban is running

fail2ban-client status   
Status
|- Number of jail:  1
`- Jail list:       ssh
```

Any hints ? Thanks for looking!

Comment: Is there anything in the auth.log more recent than that?  There are no failed login attempts in that log sample so there's nothing fail2ban *should* trigger on and what is there is from 10am but your other logs are from 3pm.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was updating each log and forgot to remove that one. IF you notice just after, there's a reference saying the auth.log is empty. I'll remove it, actually I run again and it's still empty.

Comment: That's your problem then.  fail2ban looks at that log and blocks IP addresses based on what it finds in there.  If there's nothing in there, there's nothing for it to block.

Comment: @Ladadadada thanks for looking btw! So, I need to understand why my ssh wrong login attempts are not being logged ? is this related with iptables ?

Comment: not sure if related but I deleted and recreated /var/log/auth.log, because I needed to empty it, to debug the situation :T

Comment: Ok did  service rsyslog restart and now I've got the log back. Going to update my post!

Comment: Oh I think rsyslog restart did the job ssh: connect to host xxxxx port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> not sure if related but I deleted and recreated /var/log/auth.log, because I needed to empty it, to debug the situation

This could well be the problem. It's likely that the syslog daemon is still writing to the original fd. You should try restarting the syslog daemon to see if it starts to log to the correct file.

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Once you have messages going to the auth.log it should start working.

Comment: Hours of searching, this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes this is because the `__bsd_syslog_verbose` is wrong. fail2ban expects /var/log/auth.log to start with `YYYY.MM.DD` (ie: 2014.10.15) yet the logs read `MMM DD` (ie: Oct 15)

To fix this you will need to do the following:

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.local
```

Edit `common.local` and set:

```
__bsd_syslog_verbose = (<[^.]+ [^.]+>)
```

Restart fail2ban :

Ubuntu (don't use restart):

```
sudo service fail2ban stop
sudo service fail2ban start
```

Comment: Glad it could help. I read every possible post available to mankind before figuring this out... Why this issue cropped up in the first place I'll never know. It was working fine before.

Comment: I know!!! I had the same thing, first it worked. Then I changed some rules in iptables-multiport.conf and all of a sudden it didn't work anymore (even after putting the original file back). Anyway, it's all good now!

Comment: The common.local file needs a [DEFAULT] section header, correct?

Comment: @rdvdijk I'm not sure, it's been a long time. I literally just did what was described in the answer.

Comment: does not work. hangs on stop.

Answer (score 3):

Issue in pyinotify:

https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/878

```
in /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf or /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

I changed `"backend = auto"` to `"backend = polling"` and everything works as expected ;)

```
service fail2ban stop
service fail2ban start
```

Comment: in my case this was indeed the problem. I put `polling` and fail2ban started to ban as expected. no idea why this answer get down voted, it solved my problem. upvoted.

Comment: did not solve mine

Answer (score 0):

The /var/log/auth.log was empty for a long time, so after running the command: service rsyslog restart

Now after the ssh wrong login attempt the ip is banned!